# when Session.sendToTarget() returns false?

Tags: java, quickfix

Can anyone tell me, in which circumstances quickfix.Session.sentToTarget(message, sessionId) returns false. Actually we i tried to send order to aceptor, it returns false, not throw any exception. Don't know why this happening every thing seems to be fine.

```
public void sendOrder(SessionID sessionId){
        ClOrdID order_id = new ClOrdID();
        order_id.setValue("121ifkaar");

        OrdType type = new OrdType(OrdType.LIMIT);

        OrderQty quantity = new OrderQty();
        quantity.setValue(new Double(79955));

        NewOrderSingle newOrderSingle = new NewOrderSingle(order_id, new Side(Side.SELL), new TransactTime(), type );
            newOrderSingle.set(new Account("ifkaar123"));
            newOrderSingle.set(new Symbol("USD"));
            newOrderSingle.set(new Currency("United State Doller"));
            Message msg =  (Message)newOrderSingle;
            try{
            boolean result = Session.sendToTarget(msg, sessionId);
            if(result){
                System.out.println("Message Send:   "+result);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Message Not send:   "+result);
            }
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

Comment: Aug 7, 2012 4:25:05 PM quickfix.mina.initiator.InitiatorIoHandler sessionCreated
INFO: MINA session created for FIX.4.4:->:FXallTrade: local=/127.0.0.1:37670, class org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketSessionImpl, remote=/127.0.0.1:3000
Aug 7, 2012 4:25:05 PM quickfix.mina.initiator.InitiatorIoHandler sessionCreated
INFO: MINA session created for FIX.4.4:->:FXallStream: local=/127.0.0.1:37671, class org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketSessionImpl, remote=/127.0.0.1:3000
Message Not send: false

Comment: no i do not find answer yet. I you have solution than please share with me.

Comment: As written before, when you start your application, the HeartBeat messages flow in both directions?

Comment: yeah its working. Connection was not establishing. Now it's working..

Comment: Now it's working but..what have you modified?

Comment: there was problem in .cfg file, I was using wrong targetCompId, that's why connection was not establishing b/w initiator and acceptor.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you start your Initiator, you will see the HeartBeat messgages (tag 35=0) flowing from and to the counterparty?

Comment: I also got that problem. My HeartBear message (tag 35 = 5) and result = false. What's problem?